# How can i sort a List<string> by digits from lower to higher when the digits are part of the strings?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a List and in this case for example the first index is:

```
"07:53 אזעקה באשדוד, ביתר עילית, גן יבנה, מעלה אדומים, קריית מלאכי ובמ״א באר"
```

This is a title it's a string but i consider it as a title.
The index is: "1. hello"
Index 2 is: "5. hello world"

And so on for example index 7 is: "66. hi all"

The problem is that in index 7 i have "66.
And in index 2 "5.
And in index 9 i have "3.

The numbers with the point after it are part of the string but i still want to sort the List according to the digits in the strings.

This is how i create each time a List

```
public List<string> GetResponsers(string contents)
{
    string responser = "";
    List<string> threadList = new List<string>();
    int f = 0;
    int startPos = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        string firstTag = "<FONT CLASS='text16b'>";
        string lastTag = "&n";
        f = contents.IndexOf(firstTag, startPos);
        if (f == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        int g = contents.IndexOf(lastTag, f);
        startPos = g + lastTag.Length;
        responser = contents.Substring(f + 22, g - f - 22);
        threadList.Add(responser);
    }
    SortList(threadList);
    return threadList;
}
```

And this is how i sort it:

```
public List<string> SortList(List<string> thread)
{
    thread = thread
        .OrderBy(str =>
         {
             var match = Regex.Match(str, @"^([-+]?\d+)");
             return match.Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) : int.MaxValue;
         })
         .ToList();
    responsers.Add(new List<string>(thread));
    return thread;
}
```

The problem is for example in a List that the first index ( index 0 ) which is the title is like this:

This is index 0: 07:53 אזעקה באשדוד, ביתר עילית, גן יבנה, מעלה אדומים, קריית מלאכי ובמ״א באר
This one should not be sort as number but since it have a number in the end: 07:53 it will sort it and put it in index number 7
Since it have 07

Or if i had another List that in index 0 there is: 07:48 אזעקה במ״א מרחבים
So again because the 07 it will put this index 0 at index 7

But i need that in any cases index 0 will be in the end the last index

The SortList method is working but in cases like 07:48 אזעקה במ״א מרחבים it will put it in index 07 and not just in the last index. 07:48 should not be part of the other number 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.

And always the numbers in the strings start like this: "1. 
number,point,space

"2. 
"55.

But 07:43 is not a number that should be sorted with the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it enough to check for the dot (`.`) after your index number as well?

```
public List<string> SortList(List<string> thread)
{
    thread = thread
        .OrderBy(str =>
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(str, @"^([-+]?\d+)\.");
            return match.Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) : int.MaxValue;
        })
        .ToList();
    responsers.Add(thread); // was: responsers.Add(new List<string>(thread));
    return thread;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class that stores the string your currently creating a list of and a numeric value to sort by. Then change your sorting method to just use the numeric field from the new class.